# OSB 12c - Proxy service timeout

Tags: osb

Is that possible to configure timeout for proxy service at application level rather than at the server level domain configuration. I need to set a connection timeout for my service below the timeout setting that we already have in server configuration

Please let me know the ways to achieve this

Comment: There's a timeout setting in the *transport* tab of a proxy service and business service. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: In business service setting we can find timeout setting. There is no such setting in the proxy service